# How to rearrange items inside directories in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons

In all previous versions of the Windows OS, one is able to move and rearrange items inside folders to their liking. But Windows 7 does not allow this, it moves the items itself and does not allow their positions to be changed. Why is this and is there a solution to this huge drawback?

Thanks

Comment: The search feature, better view settings, and libraries are much nicer than being able to randomly place your icons, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

They have dropped this ability.

The reason for it is the new Grid-like view in Windows Vista and 7, If you press the slider at the top, there are many views that automatically redraw the entire area.

This is not an excuse as to why they no longer provide it, but my guess is it is simply down to a lack of demand. On top of this, I think Microsoft are trying to encourage people to either use a sort or just use the search at the top as it works very well and should be better/faster than trying to manually rearrange icons in every folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but the solution isn't exactly 'straight forward':

**[How do I kill Auto-Arrange?](http://help.lockergnome.com/vista/kill-Auto-Arrange--ftopict71356.html)**